# Не удаляется footer методом removeFooterView

Tags: android, listview

Я использую футер для того, чтобы было видно, что данные подгружаются в список. И при последней загрузке данных я пытаюсь удалить этот футер. Но почему то он не удаляется. А если вызвать метод после инициализации listview, то футер удаляется сразу.

Добавление футера:

```
        if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.news_item, newsList);
        if (mListView.getFooterViewsCount() == 0) {
            mListView.addFooterView(mFooter, null, false);
        }
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Удаление футера:

```
            @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(isEndNewsList)) {
                isLastItemVisible = false;
                getNewsFromServer();
            }
            if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && isEndNewsList) {
                if (!isLastItemVisible) {
                    isLastItemVisible = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.list_end), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Проблемы того, что код не попадает сюда нет, toast вызывается без проблем.

Comment: У вас случайно в методе `getNewsFromServer();` footer не пересоздается? или в другом месте

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish нет, такую небольшую проверку сделал
            if (mListView.getFooterViewsCount() == 0) {
                mListView.addFooterView(mFooter, null, false);
            }
дебаггером прошелся и туда только раз заходит

Comment: Так вас эта проверка не спасает от ситуации когда хотите удалить объект из вью. Вы при инициализации списка создали вью для футера и добавили его, затем в процесе выполнения вы футер пересоздали, соответственно футер который уже в списке и футер который у вас объявлен это разные  объекты

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish, спасибо, Вы оказались правы! Перекинул создание футера в onCreate и теперь он создается единожды.